# Applications Deployment with MDT

Tags: mdt-2010

I have added a install for Silver light to my MDT server, so it can get installed when the image gets deployed.

When I boot them machines it is asking me to install the applications, how can i get it to auto install the apps without prompting. I have added this line to the rules -

I thought that would but seems to make no difference. I'm sure i must have missed something somewhere?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install programs silently and automatically with MDT, certain install commands will be needed. For Silverlight, please see this this TechNet article: [Silverlight Installation Switches](http://blogs.technet.com/b/extreme/archive/2009/04/02/silverlight-installation-switches.aspx)
The Quiet switch should be all you need in this case, so the command line of silverlight.exe /q should allow Silverlight to install silently and with no interaction on your part.

Comment: I have got the switches in there, but on the install it is still prompting me if i want to actually install or not. If i tick the button at the start of the install it does install quiet, but i dont want to be asked the question

Comment: I just tested this in MDT, and the /q switch allowed silverlight to install with no prompting. How are you adding the application to MDT and what is your command line? Also, in your OP, you mentioned adding a line to the rules, but didn't put what line you added.

Comment: @beakersoft Did you get this working? If not, can you detail how you are adding the application to MDT?

Comment: I did get it working (with the /q switch in the command) but i had to do something else as well, its been that long i'm not sure what it was! I think there was something in the Task Sequence i had to enable/change to stop the prompt

Answer (score 0):

So you've got the applications in your deployment share, but you don't want to be prompted by the deployment wizard for which applications to install?

If you have several applications to install, you can do one of two things:

1. Add an "Install Application" step to your task sequence for each application. Within each step, select "Install a single application" and choose which one.
2. Place your applications into an 'Application bundle' in the applications section of your deployment share, and choose to install that bundle in the "Install Application" step within your task sequence.

MDT will stop asking you which applications you wish to install if you've done either of the above.